# how to create pairs in a numpy array based on the frequency of data

Tags: python, numpy

I have some numbers and want to make some pairs out of them. This is my data:

```
points=np.arange(0,10)
```

And this array defines how to make the pairs:

```
repetition= np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

Then, I want to create such pairs:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9)]
```

I have tried the following code but it is not giving me what I want:

```
L=[]
k=0
for r in repetition:
    last= k+r
    L.append(points[k:last])
    k= last
lmax= len(max(L,key=len))
L=[ np.concatenate((np.full(lmax-len(l),None),l))  for l in L ]
L= [[e for e in l if e] for l in zip(*L)]
result= sorted([p  for l in L for p in zip(l,l[1:])])
```

I have also uploaded a fig to clarify my request more. red lines are connecting the pairs. I reality, my data are much more complex but they follow the same role. The `repetition` defines that each value of `points` should be connected to which one. In advance, I do appreciate any help. Thanks for devoting time.

[image]

Comment: Dear @Ashutosh Kumar, the way I want to pair them is exactly like `repetition`. Firtst value in `repetition` is `1`, so the first variable should be paired with next one. For the second, `repetition` is `1`, so it should be connected with next one. For the third variable of `points`, in the `repetition` we reach `2`: it means variables numbered 3 and 4 of `points` should be connected to their next two variable (2 with 4 and 3 with 5). For the fifth variable of `points` the number in `repetition` is 3 which means variables named 4,5 and 6 should be paired with 7, 8, 9, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code:

```
repetition= np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])

pairs = []
value = 0
for r in repetition:
    subpairs = np.arange(r)
    for s in subpairs:
        n = len(subpairs)
        a = value+s
        b = value+s+n
        pairs.append((a,b))
    value += n
```

result:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 5), (4, 7), (5, 8), (6, 9), (7, 10), (8, 11), (9, 12)]
```

Comment: Dear @fullfine. Thanks for you big help. It is exactly what I needed. Just one comment. It is giving me the indices. HOw can I have the real data? In reality my data do not strat from 0. And also how can I get rid of the points created after the end of my limit? I mean I do not need pairs after `(6,9)`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you open another stack question I'll answer you there.